# o2 sensor problem

Tags: vw, o2-sensor, seat

I have a SEAT Toledo 1.6L 16V with engine code **AZD**.

I was getting an error code for the Bank1 Sensor1 because of a blown fuse but I didn't know that then and I replaced the Bank1 Sensor 1 with this [sensor](https://www.teileshop.de/products/1041135-lambdasonde.htm).
I don't have the original sensor, sadly I threw it away thinking it was bad.

Now I am getting the following error codes:

- *P0135 : Oxygen O2 Sensor Heater Circuit Malfunction (Bank 1, Sensor 1)*
- *P1183 : Heated oxygen sensor (HO2S) reference voltage - short to positive*

There are 5 wires on the O2 sensor

[image]

**What I checked:**

- I checked the heater wires for resistance there is 6 Ohm of
  resistance.
- I checked the wiring harness and there is no visible damage and everything seems normal on the harness, I even check for short with the continuity tool of a multimeter.

  - I checked the wires of the sensor, they are not melted.
  - Replaced coolant temperature sensor
  - Replaced MAP sensor

I am thinking maybe I bought the wrong o2 sensor. 
Can anyone help me? Any tips or suggestions on what to check.